# PyQt5. Script runs when monitor is attached, but errors without monitor

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyqt, pyqt5

I am running a python script using the following PyQt5 libraries:

- PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets
- PyQt5.QtWidgets
- PyQt5.QtCore

I am also running BeautifulSoup (bs4).

The script basically opens a url and scrapes a javascript rendered table from a website. When I run the script on the Raspberry Pi with the monitor attached, it works fine. However, the goal is to schedule and run the script without a monitor attached. When I ssh to my Pi without a connected monitor and run the script remotely, I get the following error message:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does anybody have an idea whether it is possible to run the script without a monitor attached? Or am I completely wrong and it's a different issue?

Here is the script that I am trying to run:

```
import bs4 as bs
import csv
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from time import localtime, strftime

local_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", localtime())
date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime())

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()

def main():
    page = Page('https://example.com/')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
    tables = soup.findAll('table')
    prices_out = []
    for table in tables:
        if table.findParent("table") is None:
            table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
            # print(table_rows)
            for tr in table_rows:
                td = tr.find_all('td')
                # print(td.text)
                row = [i.text for i in td]
                if row:
                    row = [r.replace('$', '') for r in row]
                    row = [r.replace(',', '') for r in row]
                    row.append(local_time)
                    prices_out.append(row)

    filename = 'example_raw_' + str(local_time) + '.csv'
    with open(filename, "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(prices_out)
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: install xvfb: `sudo apt-get install xvfb` and run: `xvfb-run python your_script.py`

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly